# Overriding properties from abstract class in Salesforce Apex

Tags: properties, salesforce, apex-code

I have an abstract class in apex with several properties that I would like to override in a child class. According to the documentation, properties support both the override and virtual access modifiers. However, when I try to use either of them in either the parent or child class, I get an error saying that variables cannot be marked as virtual/override. Here is a facsimile of the code that causes this error:

```
public abstract class Row{
    public virtual double value{
        get{return value==null ? 0 : value;}
        set;
    }
}

public class SummaryRow extends Row{
    private list<Row> childRows;
    public override double value{
        get{
            totalValue = 0;
            for(Row childRow:childRows){
                totalvalue += childRow.value;
            }
            return totalValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this functionality not supported, or is there something that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know that is a mistake in the documentation. I've only been able to apply the  `override` and `virtual` modifiers to methods.  You can, of course, get the desired effect by manually writing your property getter/setter methods:

```
public abstract class TestRow {
    public Double value;

    public virtual Double getValue() {
        return value==null ? 0 : value;
    }

    public void setValue(Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class SummaryTestRow extends TestRow {
    private list<TestRow> childRows;

    public override Double getValue() {
        Double totalValue = 0;
        for(TestRow childRow : childRows){
            totalValue += childRow.value;
        }

        return totalValue;  
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but I was hoping that there was a cleaner way and I had just messed something up with the syntax.

Comment: does this work with 2 way bindings in Visualforce tho? can it be bound to an input field?